# Dismiss secondViewController when thirdViewController presenting in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have tree view controller. when secondViewController showing up, I try to present thirdViewController in this time I want to dismiss secondViewController because whenever I want to try dismiss in thirdViewController I want to see firstViewController not see the second one. here is my code that I have tried

```
self.presentViewController(thirtVC, animated: true) { () -> Void in

                dispatch_after(0, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: { () -> Void in

                    })
                })

            }
```

and it is not working for this case. Please where would be issue.

Comment: Are you sure you are not presenting your `secondViewController` and pushing it in `UINavigationController` ??

Comment: Yes There is no UINavigationController in thirdVC. but firstViewController has UINavigationController.

Comment: I am just asking how are you adding secondViewController ??

Comment: I just add secondViewController like thirdViewController.         self.presentViewController(secondVC, animated: true) { () -> Void in

                })

            }

Comment: like this `self.presentViewController(secondVC, animated: true)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are presenting a view then you have to dismiss your viewController, then present another viewController like this,

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
       self.presentViewController(thirtVC, animated: true) { () -> Void in
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not want I want. if I write that code, user will see the firstViewController  before thirdViewController appear.